# combining non-uniform size 2D arrays into a 3D array in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing, numpy-ufunc

I've searched on stackoverflow but could not find an answer to this specific question. Sorry if it is a naive question, I am a newbie to python. I have three 2d arrays of shapes

Shape of `arr_X  =` (1,**8**), Shape of  `arr_Y  =` (1,**8**), & Shape of
 `arr_Z  =` (**5**,8).
From these 2D arrays I want to make one 3D array of shape (**5**, **8**, **8**).
Can anyone help me to form the 3D array?

Comment: total values in `arr_X, arr_Y, arr_Z` is `1x8+1x8+5x8=56`, but the 3D array you want, it has a total of `5x8x8=320` values! They at least have to be equal, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need to check now